# Jquery count characters in an element and give too short ones a padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have a navigation on which some links (those who are shorter than 9 characters) get a padding.

So jquery should count the lenght of the a element of the navigation and give a padding to every element that is shorter than 9 characters.

Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
var liborder = $('#oe_menu li a').val();
if(liborder.length <= 9) {
    $(this).css("padding", "8px");
}
```

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#oe_menu li a').each(function() {
   var self = $(this);
   if (self.text().length <= 9) {
       self.css("padding", "8px");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over elements and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `val()` to get the string of a hyperlink. `text()` is intended for text content of tag while `val()` is for getting value of selects and inputs:

```
$('#oe_menu li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length <= 9) {
        $(this).css("padding", "8px");
    }
});
```